# An error in histogram from a one-column data set in R

Tags: r, import, histogram

**Background:**

I have one column of Data consisting of 400 rows stored in a csv file. The data can be easily imported into your RStudio using the R code below.

**Question:**

I'm wondering how to get ***a histogram of this Data?*** Specifically, after I import this Data into R studio and run `hist(Data)`, I get the following error message:

`Error in hist.default(D) : 'x' must be numeric`

**P.S.** I initially created the data using `Initial = rbeta(400, 2, 3); final = sample(c(Initial,0.5,0.6), size = 400, prob = c(rep(.98/400,400),.005,.015), replace = T)`.

**Here is my small R code:**

```
id <- "0B5V8AyEFBTmXcURlQ0tzNjBEVFU"

Data <- read.csv(paste0("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=",id,"&export=download"))

hist(Data)  ## HERE I get the error
```

Comment: How about `hist(Data$x)`?

Comment: @r2evans, still the same problem. I even deleted the "x" from the csv file but again get the same error. I originally created data using `Initial = rbeta(400, 2, 3)
final = sample(c(Initial,0.5,0.6), size = 400,
               prob = c(rep(.98/400,400),.005,.015),
               replace = T)` and then saved it as csv fle

Comment: @neilfws, again the same problem persists!

Comment: I can't help any further without seeing some sample data. You mention creating a vector named `final` but `hist(final)` works just fine, so the problem is in how you created, downloaded, and/or imported the CSV file. Please include `dput(head(Data))`.

Comment: @r2evans, the link to the data is right there in my question you can easily import that into your Rstudio.

Comment: It seems you already have your answer. The point is not always what *should* be happening but instead what is happening in your environment. For instance, if your `Data` turned out to be a HTTP-404 error (not sure if that can happen with `read.csv`, but ...) then it would not matter what *I* see as much as what you have in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.csv` uses `header = TRUE` by default so without `x`, the first value in your file becomes the header. So you need:

```
Data <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B5V8AyEFBTmXcURlQ0tzNjBEVFU&export=download", 
                 header = FALSE)
hist(Data$V1)
```

Comment: `V1, V2, V3...` are the default column names for a data frame in the absence of supplied headers.

Comment: `?read.csv` or `rownames(Data)` will answer that for you. Rows are numbered by default.